# How to run on demand mode in PhpStorm/ IntelliJ for a VM

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I want to run XDebug using the "[On Demand Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-xdebug.html#on_demand_mode)" in PhpStorm or IntelliJ. The problem is that it's running on a VM, and the documentation above seems to only describe when using PHP locally.

How can I run XDebug "On Demand Mode" in PhpStorm for a Virtual Machine or Remote Host?

Comment: AFAIK there is no difference -- at least I do not see any super-special settings right now. As long as you can make "normal" remote debug working then"on demand" should work as well.

Comment: The issue I saw when reading it is that they say to specify the path of the PHP interpreter. The issue with that is of course I'm running PHP through an Apache Server on a VM. Not Locally!

Comment: OK -- "On Demand" meant to work with CLI interpreters as it need to pass extra parameter (path to xdebug extension) when you click Debug button. It will work for local or remote interpreter (if you can launch PHP remotely with a script name as parameter then you can also able to pass that extra xdebug parameter as well). You cannot pass such parameter when working with local or remote web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/whatever) .. as PHP in this case is run by that web server and not by PhpStorm.

Comment: So how can I get it to work on Apache? Is there an alternative way of getting the same effect on Apache?

Comment: That option will not work on web server controlled PHP -- PhpStorm does not launch it (PHP) and therefore cannot pass that extra parameter. Plus, PHP in most cases (Apache module; FastCGI; php-fpm) would already be running .. and you simply cannot pass such argument to already running process.

Comment: If anything -- you have to look at functionality that your web server can offer (e.g. somehow switch between different php.ini/different PHP installation -- don't know -- by using different domain names/virtual servers where each of them is configured to use different PHP; manually editing php.ini and restarting Apache before making debug request etc) ... No other ideas.